# How do you have a TextField value change trigger an update to another piece of data in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I’m trying to learn Swift, SwiftUI, and Combine and am new to iOS in general. Eventually I want to have a list that you can search, filter, and sort.

So far I have filtering working when I use `onEditingChanged` within the TextField but that requires hitting enter. I just can’t figure out how to trigger `activePeople` to update when the TextField `filterText`  changes so that the `activePeople` list filters *while* you type.

I’ve gotten a version to work when I filter the list within a ForEach in the view (see commented out code) but eventually the filtering and sorting will get more complicated and it seems to make more sense to have it outside of that view. Let me know if this is not the right approach for whatever reason.

Here’s the code so far:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var filterText: String = “”
    @Published var activePeople: [Person] = []

    private var allPeople : [Person] = [
        Person( id: 1000, name: “Alexa” ),
        Person( id: 1001, name: “Anaïs” ),
        Person( id: 1002, name: “Earl” ),
        Person( id: 1003, name: “Elba” ),
        Person( id: 1004, name: "Emil” ),
        Person( id: 1005, name: “Janeth” ),
        Person( id: 1006, name: “Joselyn” ),
        Person( id: 1007, name: “Lupita” ),
        Person( id: 1008, name: “Mellie” ),
        Person( id: 1009, name: “Vanita” ),
    ]

    init() {
        activePeople = allPeople
    }

    func filterList() {
        if ( filterText == “” ) {
            activePeople = allPeople
        } else {
            activePeople = allPeople.filter( { $0.name.localizedStandardContains( filterText ) } )
        }
    }

}

struct Person: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField(“Filter Text”, text: $model.filterText, onEditingChanged: {_ in self.model.filterList()}
                    )
                }
                Section {
                    Text( "Filtered by: \(model.filterText)” )
                    ForEach( model.activePeople ) { person in
//                        if ( self.model.filterText == “” || person.name.localizedStandardContains( self.model.filterText )) {
                            Text( person.name )
//                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(Model())
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to observe the changes of a textfield input, you can observer the variable in a model. Removing the filtering logic from the view would be probably a good idea as well.
An example of this would be to start observing the `filterText` when the model inits. Also, remember to keep a reference to a cancellable returned from `sink`.
What we do here is every time the value from `filterText` changes (and it does because of textfield binding), we will filter the array and assign a value to the `activePeople` variable

```
 var filterCancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        filterCancellable = $filterText.sink {[weak self] currentText in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return } 
            strongSelf.activePeople = strongSelf.filterList(with: currentText)
        }
    }

    func filterList(with text: String) -> [Person] {
        if ( text == "" ) {
            return allPeople
        } else {
            return allPeople.filter( { $0.name.localizedStandardContains( text ) } )
        }
    }
```

This way you can later do just

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Filter Text", text: $model.filterText)
                }
                Section {
                    Text( "Filtered by: \(model.filterText)" )
                    ForEach( model.activePeople ) { person in
                        Text( person.name )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply filtering in your ContentView:

```
ForEach(model.activePeople.filter({ self.model.filterText.isEmpty ||
                                   $0.name.localizedStandardContains(self.model.filterText)})) { person in
                            Text( person.name )
                    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep this out of the view? Eventually I’d like to use multiple filters and apply a sort. Is keeping all this logic in the view the way SwiftUI is supposed to work?

Comment: You could move it to a separate struct responsible for filtering data.